# Using a tkinter list widget to lively display database entries?

Tags: python, database, tkinter

So I was curious on how one might create a tkinter list widget, and every couple seconds have it refresh, and display all database entries. I'm fairly new to coding, so am a little confused on how to do this, I know it shouldn't be too hard. I'm not asking for an entire working piece of code, just some guidance on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Google might help you more on this than SO, since there's so much pieces involved. Start off making a minimal tkinter list widget gui, try polling (if there's not a better way) your database (e.g. with a `threading.Timer`)  and then start putting things together...

Comment: I would never recommend threading to someone fairly new to coding. It's a complex subject that is easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely your only choice is to periodically query the database and update the UI based on the results of the query. That is, unless you have a database library that can call a function whenever it detects a change.

Tkinter makes it easy to do something like this with the `after` method. This lets you schedule something to run at some point in the future. You can use this to, in effect, create an infinitely refreshing list. It would look something like this:

```
def refresh_list():
    results = do_query()
    listbox.delete(0, "end")
    listbox.insert(0, *results)
    listbox.after(1000, refresh_list)
```

The above will do a query, delete the items in the listbox, then insert the results of the query in the listbox. Finally, it will schedule itself to run again in 1000ms.

Of course, this is far from production-ready. You should probably keep track of whatever was selected in the listbox, remember the position of the scrollbar, and/or only insert new items and delete removed items rather than replace the whole list. The basic concept is what's important - do a query, update the listbox, then call the function again in a second or two.

Assuming the queries only take a couple hundred milliseconds or so to do, it will all work just fine. If the query takes much longer than that, you'll probably need to put the query in a thread, and then have the thread communicate with the GUI thread when there is data to be displayed.

Comment: This is a great place to start, I will look into all of this.